# how do I print individual strings in a list made from lines of csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

For the below csv file, i'm trying to use the first item in 3rd to 6th rows (aka row 2 to 5) each as input for a function, so I need to be able to call them. then I need to do the same for first items in the 8th and 9th rows. how would I do that?

```
NETFLIX
PROGRAMS
Halt and Catch Fire,Drama,Christopher Cantwell and Christopher C. Rogers,2014
Arrival,Drama,Denis Villeneuve,2016
Us,Horror,Jordan Peele,2018
Matrix; The,Sci-Fi,The Wachowskis,1999
SUBSCRIBERS
John,john123,password
Farah,f206,abcdef
```

So far, I put each line into a list of strings and when I call line[0] to give me the first item in the list, I get this:

```
PROGRAMS
Halt and Catch Fire
Arrival
Us
Matrix; The
SUBSCRIBERS
John
Farah
```

which is kind of what I want, but I don't want all the rows at the same time. I want to be able to call each 3rd to 6th rows together, then 8th and 9th together to get this:

```
Halt and Catch Fire
Arrival
Us
Matrix; The
```

and

```
John
Farah
```

the point of doing this is so I could use the elements of these rows as parameters for functions I created.

Comment: Sometihng like `[lines[i][0] for i in range(3, 7)]`

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gives me an error saying `list index out of range`

Comment: Why don't you just make separate lists for the programs and subscribers, rather than putting everything in one list?

Answer (score 2):

Rows with only one column separate the lists.  You could store the lists by the last single-row columns seen.  Note `defaultdict` will create its default object (in this case an empty list) if the key in the dictionary doesn't exist.  Prevents having to check if the key is already present in the dictionary before appending.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = defaultdict(list)
    next(f) # skip first row
    for row in r:
        if len(row) == 1: # single column, remember the list name
            key = row[0]
        else:
            data[key].append(row[0]) # append to last list remembered.

print(data)
print(data['PROGRAMS'])
print(data['SUBSCRIBERS'])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'PROGRAMS': ['Halt and Catch Fire', 'Arrival', 'Us', 'Matrix; The'], 'SUBSCRIBERS': ['John', 'Farah']})
['Halt and Catch Fire', 'Arrival', 'Us', 'Matrix; The']
['John', 'Farah']
```

Then you can iterate on one of the lists to call some function:

```py
for program in data['PROGRAMS']:
    some_function(program)
```